# Photoshop Javascript - check to see if file is open (then switch to active document), if not, open

Tags: javascript, photoshop

I am trying to see, via Photoshop JSX, if a given file is already open in Photoshop. If so, I want to switch to it.  If not, I would like to open it. I realize this is fairly basis but would appreciate any help!

```js
var openFiles = app.documents;
if (openFiles.includes filename) {
  app.activeDocument = filename;
  }
 else {
   open(filename);
   }
```

Comment: I cannot find app.documents.includes in the docs, what Version are you working on?

Comment: Harry, thank you. I'm using the newest CC 2018 version. It actually is not in the docs. I thought it might work as javascript code independent of photoshop's functions. This might not be possible...I see you can get the list of recent files but not necessarily all that are actively open.

Answer (score 0):

No Photoshop for testing here but i can give you an idea about how to deal with your issue anyway. There is no built-in function in JavaScript as you assume unfortuantely.

What might help you is to iterate trough all documents:

```
for (i=0;i<app.documents.length;i++){
   if (app.documents[i].source.indexOf(filename) != -1){
         //the file you are looking for is already open
    }
}
```

In above Code, only .length and .indexOf are JavaScript native, all other stuff is Adobe specific. What i am not sure of is if "app.documents[i].source" will contain the source filename, if not you can try all other properties of "DocumentInfo" from the Adobe docs...

Comment: Thank you, Harry. It's throwing an error for me (undefined is not an object) but I will experiment with it further and update here when I have a solution. You got me off to a great start and I appreciate it!